# Calculate image width

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

In this code below, a picture can be loaded into openCV and then the region of interest RIO can be created by just selecting a box around something with the mouse, then press `enter`.

What I am trying to do is ***measure the apparent width in pixels*** of the ROI. I am going thru some of the theory in [this pyimagesearch blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/) for calculating distances in images.

I have a folder called images and a .png file named 1 within the folder.

```
import cv2


image = cv2.imread("images/1.png")
cv2.imshow("image", image)
marker = cv2.selectROI("image", image, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)


print(marker)

print(marker[1]-marker[3])
```

The output is below but I am not really sure how/if this can be used. I think its stating the ROI x,y height & width but I am not sure:

```
(317, 181, 269, 359)
-178
>>>
```

Any tips help... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.selectROI()` returns a 2D rectangle with `(x, y, width, height)` (see [the Rect constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#a5a41149f4b012b9f323b5913454375a1) - that object is created from [selectROI()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga8daf4730d3adf7035b6de9be4c469af5)).

So, if you want to measure the apparent width in pixels, you need `marker[2]`.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to help me with this post? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44871/cv2-error-opencv3-4-3-215assertion-failed-empty-in-function