# cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

Would anyone have a tip on how to fix this empty function error in OpenCV? I am attempting to follow the [guides on OpenCV.org](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html)

The script will detect a face in an image and draw boxes around detections.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv



face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

img = cv.imread('images/1.png')
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]


cv.imshow('img',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get an error:

```
>>> 
=== RESTART: C:/Users/Desktop/distance-to-camera/selectHaar2.py ===
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/distance-to-camera/selectHaar2.py", line 11, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

Comment: I think this may be due to the fact that XML file is missing or the path to it is incorrect. Could you please check that? Maybe you coul try with the full path for the `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`file

Comment: Yes that worked thank you. If you post an answer ill hit the green check box. Also do you know the difference between the haar XMLs for faces? Whats a best practice between frontface_alt2, frontalface_default, _alt_tree, and _alt...? It seems like most tutorials use _alt or _default... Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't know the answer to the second question about the best practice.

Comment: Check whether your image is **uint8** or not: `image = image.astype(np.uint8)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be due to the fact that XML file is missing or the path to it is incorrect. Could you please check that? Maybe you coul try with the full path for the `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue and by removing special characters from the image_file_name the issue was resolved.

Example: Renaming "48172454-thymianblätter.jpg" to "48172454-thymian.jpg".